# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running ubuntu20

Tags: linux, nvidia, ubuntu-20.04

I have ubuntu 20.04. I installed nvidia-driver-460 and using it. Recently my system updates. then I got the following.
I tried to update

> **sudo apt upgrade**

I got "0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and **2 not upgraded**."

I typed: **nvidia-smi**, then I got

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running

Answer (score 3):

> **sudo apt upgrade**

"0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and **2 not upgraded**."

I could not upgrade 2 files. so, checked which files are they by the following command

> **sudo apt list --upgradable -a**

I got the following nvidi-driver libraries conflict. "**linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge/focal-updates 5.8.0-49.55~20.04.1+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1]**".

I tried to upgrade it

> sudo apt upgrade linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge

it showed, there are dependencies of libraries, so ti was not successful.

***solution***

1. Downgrade the nvidia-driver to nvidia-driver-450 or the lower version you prefer. go to "Software & Updates" and select lower version and press Apply changes like shown below
   [image: nvidia-driver-450]
2. Reboot your system
3. upgrade the nvidia-driver back to nvidia-driver-460 like previous
   [image: nvidia-driver-460]
4. Reboot your system again, it works prefectly

Comment: Also worked for me with `nvidia-driver-470`

Answer (score 0):

1.Firstly, you can use the command "nvcc -V" to check wheater you have NVIDIA driver.If you already install NVIDIA driver, you can continue as following steps.Otherwise you should install NVIDIA driver firstly.

2.Secondly, you can find your NVIDIA driver's version by following command "ls /usr/src | grep nvidia".

3.Lastly, you should install the corresponding version by following command

- sudo apt install dkms
- sudo dkms install -m nvidia -v 535.54.03 (warning:user your corresponding version by second step)

I'm glad to glad to answer your question if you hava any problems about my solution.

Reference:https://blog.csdn.net/wjinjie/article/details/108997692